# Flex 4 Remove dynamically created component from the canvas

Tags: flex4, element

I am dynamically adding items to a stage. How ever I am having a hard time addressing the objects to remove them from the stage.

I wrote some code to do the remove but it only works with non dynamically created items.

http://pastebin.com/3cKvdVsC <= code sample here (yes I know its messy, I was experimenting with a framework I have never seen before in a very trial and error fashion).

I use "AddItemToCanvas()" to create items and "removeSelected()" to remove selected items from the stage.

In thoery there must be a way to address dynamically created items by name and remove them...

Please and thank you to anyone who can shed some light for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was found here.

http://www.billdwhite.com/wordpress/?p=296

An invaluable article for anyone moving to Flex 4 from flex 3.

Comment: I also recommend this read: as a comparison.http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf62b90-7fe9.html